# Не корректно работает функция проверки на дробные числа

Tags: javascript

Знаю, что это можно проверить используя метод isInteger. Но, в моем случае, не могу понять почему альтернативное решение не работает. В первом варианте, проверка на целочисленные значения, возвращает true как и должно быть. А, вот вторая функция которая проверяет на дробные числа возвращает ложь, хотя условие поменять на отрицание. Подскажите пож. в чем причина?

```js
function test(num) {
    if(num % 2 === 0 || num % 2 === 0) {
        console.log(true)
    } else {
        console.log(false)
    }
}

test(2)

function test2(num) {
    if(num % 2 != 0 || num % 2 != 0) {
        console.log(true)
    } else {
        console.log(false)
    }
}

test(2.23)
```

Comment: Ни одна из этих функций не проверяет число на целость

Comment: Писать два идентичных условия через || не имеет смысла

Comment: У вас, наверное, опечатка, вы вызываете оба раза первую функцию.

Comment: @AlexeyTen как это не проверяет? Попробуйте передать этой функции любое дробное число и выдаст false.    function test(num) {
    if(num % 2 === 0 || num % 2 === 0) {
        console.log(true)
    } else {
        console.log(false)
    }
}

test(2)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty точно, дело именно в ней. Теперь все проверки работают, спасибо!

Comment: @salco202020 передайте туда 13

Comment: @AlexeyTen там опечатка))  if(num % 2 === 0 || num % 2 === 1) так все работает))